# Double mongodb request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi i have two requests i need in my app
but only one send a result, how can i do to make them both work?
the first one is a get of all my buildings, the second one is the same get but i sort the whole document  by campusName.

i did like that but still not working only one request sent.

```
app.get('/buildings', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await db.db('').collection('buildings').find({}).toArray(function (err, result) {
            res.send(result);
    });
        await db.db('').collection('buildings').aggregate([
        {$group : {_id: "$campusName", buildings : {$push : {buildingName : "$buildingName", phoneNumber :"$phoneNumber" }}}}
        ]).toArray(function (err, building) {
            res.send(building);
    });        
        } catch(err) {
            return res.json({
                         success: false,
                         message: 'error'
    });
        }
    });
```

that's my new query

```
app.get('/buildings', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await db.db('').collection('buildings').find({}).toArray(async (err, result) => {


        await db.db('').collection('buildings').aggregate([
        {$group : {_id: "$campusName", buildings : {$push : {buildingName : "$buildingName", phoneNumber :"$phoneNumber" }}}}
        ]).toArray((err, building) => {
            res.send(result);
            res.send(building);
        });  
    });      
        } catch(err) {
            return res.json({
                         success: false,
                         message: 'error'
    });
        }
    });
```

Finally what i did is separate the two queries in two adresses  like this and is=t's better for me to handle and manipulate on my front-end

```
app.get('/buildings', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        await db.db('').collection('buildings').find({}).toArray(function (err, result) {
            res.send(result);
    });
        } catch(err) {
        return res.json({
                     success: false,
                     message: 'error'
                 });
        }
    });

app.get('/buildings/percampus', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await db.db('').collection('buildings').aggregate([
        {$group : {_id: "$campusName", buildings : {$push : {buildingName : "$buildingName", phoneNumber :"$phoneNumber" }}}}
      ]).toArray(function (err, building) {
            res.send(building);
    });
        } catch(err) {
        return res.json({
                     success: false,
                     message: 'error'
                 }); 
        }

    });
```

Comment: just add the second mongo search one inside the first one

Comment: i tried but doesn't work :(

Comment: why not use sort to get the result in one query.

Comment: post edited i put the two queries in one but still not working just the first one

Comment: i tried res.send(result, building) but not working too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't (AFAIK) have multiple `.get` handlers on a single route. You can have multiple middlewares chained onto a single route, but not multiple handlers as only the first one will get executed. That would imply that you should get multiple responses per a single request, which is not how it works, that would actually break your Express as that's properly handled in the internals. If you want multiple things returned, run both of your queries inside that one single handler:

```
app.get('/buildings', async (req, res) => {
    let res_obj = {}
    // Then execute your queries, and place the results inside this res_obj 
    ... queries and their handling ...
    res.send(res_obj);
```

Which would ideally return something along the lines of

```
{
    first_query_res: {
        ... 
    },
    second_query_res: {
        ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send single response with both required values, Building and results.

First we will search from db and get the value of result and building then we create an object {building:'',result:''} then packing it (JSON.stringify) and then send as response.

```
app.get('/buildings', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await db.db('').collection('buildings').find({}).toArray(function (err, result) { // second db search in this
        await db.db('').collection('buildings').aggregate([
        {$group : {_id: "$campusName", buildings : {$push : {buildingName : "$buildingName", phoneNumber :"$phoneNumber" }}}}
        ]).toArray(function (err, building) {
            //res.send({building:building,result:result}); 
            // or
            res.send(JSON.stringify{building:building,result:result});

    });        
        } catch(err) {
            return res.json({
                         success: false,
                         message: 'error'
    });
        }
    });
```